# Restlet framework: how to bind to localhost only?

Tags: java, localhost, bind, restlet, restlet-2.3.1

I need to build a (standalone Java) restlet-based service that **only listens on localhost**, i.e. no requests from network are allowed.

I was trying to do the obvious:

```
Server srv = new Server(Protocol.HTTPS, "localhost", httpsPort); 
component.getServers().add(srv);
```

But the service still listens on 0.0.0.0. :-(

I went into the code and found that HttpsServerHelper ignores the hostname when creating the service:

```
this.server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(getHelped().getPort()), 0);
```

Similar code exists in plain HTTP's HttpServerHelper, where it is even more clear.

My question then is this:

**How can I configure Restlet component/service to only listen on localhost?**

Comment: ``component.getDefaultHost()``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which server you use under the hood within your standalone Restlet application. You should use a server connector other than the default one and I recommend you to use the Jetty one.

To do that, simply put the jar of the extension `org.restlet.ext.jetty` in your classpath.

In this case, using the following code should correspond to your needs:

```
component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, "localhost", 8182);
```

Here is the corresponding trace at application startup:

```
2015-09-03 09:47:22.180:INFO::jetty-7.1.6.v20100715
2015-09-03 09:47:22.211:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:8182
```

In addition, here is the link in the Restlet documentation regarding Restlet connectors: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/base/connectors.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you, that was the culprit. I was using the internal web server (because in another packaging variant I have to deploy to Weblogic), and the internal web server apparently simply ignores the listen host specification. When I added Jetty, the existing code worked immediately without changes.

Comment: P.S. May be the internal web server should log a warning if the code tries to specify the host. Costed me like 2 days of head-banging :-)

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, agreed with you for the warning!

Answer (score 2):

The easier way to achieve that is to use virtual hosts.
Virtual hosts are the first routing barrier when handling a request, especially it helps routing on a domain.

Here is a sample code that illustrates this:

```
    Component c = new Component();
    c.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

    VirtualHost host = new VirtualHost();
    host.setHostDomain("localhost");
    c.getHosts().add(host);
    host.attach(new Restlet() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
            response.setEntity("hello, world", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        }
    });

    c.start();
```

Usually, applications are attached on the default host of a component. This default host does nothing, except routing requests based on the context path of the attached application:

```
    c.getDefaultHost().attach("/contextPath1", new Test1Application());
    c.getDefaultHost().attach("/contextPath2", new Test2Application());
```

When you would like to filter calls based on other data than the request's path, virtual host may be the solution.

Here is a diagram that may help you:

http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/tutorials/2.3#part05

Comment: Thank you for the educational post, I learned quite a lot about virtual hosts. One comment for your code: the new VirtualHost() should take c.getContext(), otherwise I'm getting NPE at attach step.